# How SQLite on Android handles long strings?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm wondering how Android's implementation of SQLite handles long Strings. Reading from online documentation on sqlite, it said that strings in sqlite are limited to 1 million characters. My strings are definitely smaller.

I'm creating a simple RSS application, and after parsing a html document, and extracting text, I'm having problem saving it to a database. I have 2 tables in database, `feeds` and `articles`. RSS feeds are correctly saved and retrieved from `feeds` table, but when saving to the `articles` table, logcat is saying that it cannot save extracted text to it's column. I don't know if other columns are making problems too, no mention of them in logcat.

I'm wondering, since text is from an article on web, are signs like (",',;) creating problems? Is Android automaticaly escaping them, or I have to do that. I'm using a technique for inserting similar to one in notepad tutorial:

```
public long insertArticle(long feedid, String title, String link, String description, String h1,tring h2, String h3, String p, String image, long date) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_FEEDID, feedid);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LINK, link);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description );
    initialValues.put(KEY_H1, h1 );
    initialValues.put(KEY_H2, h2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_H3, h3);
    initialValues.put(KEY_P, p);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_ARTICLES,null, initialValues);
}
```

Column P is for extracted text, h1, h2 and h3 are for headers from a page. Logcat reports only column p to be the problem. The table is created with following statement:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ARTICLES =
    "create table articles( _id integer primary key autoincrement, feedid integer, title text, link text not null, description text," + "h1 text, h2 text, h3 text, p text, image text, date integer);";
```

Comment: Posting the actual error message and surrounding logcat context would be useful.

Comment: found error... a dumb oversight on my part...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Android is using SQLite as the backend, all fields are variable length. The default sqlite field length limit is 1 billion chars, but android may have changed this.

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't see anywhere the max length of string has been changed.