# Android : Fatal Exception on cursor.getCount

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm getting `SQLiteBlobTooBigException` exception when fetching data from table.

Here is stacktrace :

```
 Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: string or blob too big (code 18)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:968)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
```

Comment: You should look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097015/max-length-of-android-sqlite-string

Comment: What information holds in this base? Are you storing files there?

Comment: I'm storing meta only.

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati did you ever find a solution/ work around that? I am facing same issue and for me, its a text file that contains too long a text to fit.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to use length() and substr() to request only 1MB (the max for CursorWindow is 2MB), maybe it will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348784/sqliteblobtoobigexception-still-occurs-after-dividing-the-request-in-chunks-of-1). Also, you could use `context.getContentResolver().query()` with a selection that only includes the relevant columns, that way you won't load data related to the other (unnecessary) columns.